# MongoEngine 0.5: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, mongoengine

```
    >>> from mongoengine import *
    >>> connect('foo')
    >>> class Foo(Document):
    ...   bar = ListField(ReferenceField('Foo'))
    >>> a = Foo()
    >>> a.save()
    >>> b = Foo()
    >>> b.save()
    >>> a.bar.append(b)
    >>> a.save()
    >>> b.bar.append(a)
    >>> b.save()
```

Results in a "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while
calling a Python object" in MongoEngine 0.5. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

this has been fixed in the dev branch - please update.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea when this fix will be released?

Comment: 0.5.1 was released but 0.5.2 has a better fix and I'll try and get that out today!

Answer (score 0):

RTD --> http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/defining-documents.html#reference-fields

> To add a ReferenceField that references the document being defined,
>   use the string 'self' in place of the document class as the argument
>   to ReferenceField‘s constructor.

Try this:

```
class Foo(Document):
    bar = ListField(ReferenceField('self'))
```